# How to iterate through every other document from a mongo db cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo DB cursor with documents that I want to create into Dataframes. However, the documents in that cursor can have a `runTime` that's too close. Therefore I'd like to get *every other* document and make a dataframe out of those.

Attempt 1.

```
all_df_forecast = []
for doc in cursor[::2]:
    single_fc_df = pd.DataFrame(doc['data']['PRICES SPOT'])
    all_df_forecast.append(single_fc_df)
```

**Results** in: `IndexError: Cursor instances do not support slice steps`

Attempt 2.

```
all_df_forecast = []
for doc in range(0, cursor.count(), 2):
    single_fc_df = pd.DataFrame(doc['data']['PRICES SPOT'])
    all_df_forecast.append(single_fc_df)
```

**Results** in `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Right now this is how the cursor with the documents that have the data.

```
 cursor = self._collection.find({
   "Type": "f", 
   "runTime": { "$gte": model_dt_from, "$lte": model_dt_till },
   "data.PRICES SPOT.0": { "$exists": True }
 })
```

Ideally if the cursor could just have every other document based on the query I give it would be ideal. I came accross [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/), but from my understanding it skips the beginning with the number I give it. Which is why I am now tackling this after I have the cursor and creating the dataframes for every other document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cursor.next()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.next) to skip over each alternate cursor result.

As a demonstration:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

db.pytest.delete_many({})
db.pytest.insert_many([{ 'value': i+1 } for i,x in enumerate([1] * 10)])

cursor = db.pytest.find({},{ '_id': 0 })

count  = cursor.count()
print count
cursor.next()

for doc in cursor:
  print doc
  count -= 2
  print count
  if (count > 0):
    cursor.next()
```

Would return:

```
10
{u'value': 2}
8
{u'value': 4}
6
{u'value': 6}
4
{u'value': 8}
2
{u'value': 10}
0
```

The only thing you need to be aware of when calling [`cursor.next()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.next) is that the cursor actually has remaining results before you call it, otherwise you will raise an exception due to the depleted cursor. For this reason you do something like obtain the [`cursor.count()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) and then decrement and track the remaining before you decide to issue.

Note that "odd" numbered results would deplete the cursor before the check anyway, so it's really there to make sure you don't advance the cursor on even numbered results when the remaining documents are `0`.

Alternate approaches like you partly attempted are to convert the cursor to a `list` and then you can grab slices, but that means loading all results into memory, which is probably impractical for most result sets of a reasonable size.