# Get every other N documents with pymongo

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection of server stats called `stats`.

A document is added to this collection every 10 minutes, included some stats, and a timestamp.

Pretend I have this collection:

```
{"id": "something", "ts"=1}
{"id": "something", "ts"=2}
{"id": "something", "ts"=3}
{"id": "something", "ts"=4}
{"id": "something", "ts"=5}
{"id": "something", "ts"=6}
{"id": "something", "ts"=7}
{"id": "something", "ts"=8}
```

I want to retrieve every other `N` documents. Example with `N = 2`:

```
{"id": "something", "ts"=1}
{"id": "something", "ts"=3}
{"id": "something", "ts"=5}
{"id": "something", "ts"=7}
```

Example with `N = 3`:

```
{"id": "something", "ts"=1}
{"id": "something", "ts"=4}
{"id": "something", "ts"=7}
```

What is a fast and efficient way to go about doing this in pymongo?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) and [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/#exp._S_mod):

```
db.test.find({$expr: {$eq: [1, {$mod: ['$ts', N]}]}})
```

`$expr` is a query operator that was introduced in v3.6 that allows you to use aggregate query expressions like `$mod` (modulus) in a `find` query.

Comment: wait a minute, perhaps my sample data was misleading. `ts` will be a timestamp, and it is not guaranteed to always go up by one. Is there anyway to do this without using the `ts` key?

Comment: Not unless there's something else in your documents you can key off of.

Comment: @Qwerty If you can't key off `ts`, then your question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509896/how-to-iterate-through-every-other-document-from-a-mongo-db-cursor. It would help if you updated your question to show your actual documents.